# Angular Firebase Google auth with custom User data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I've found [this video](https://youtu.be/e8GA1UOj8mE) (in [code](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/google-user-auth-with-firestore-custom-data/)), and made my Auth Service just like this, except my User Interface is like:

```
interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  photoURL: string;
  displayName: string;
  status?: string;
  karma?: number;
}
```

Status should be the typical online/busy/away...etc, and karma would be a number, and the users could rate each other.
So my **updateUserData** function (where he saves the user's data into Firestore) is like this:

```
private updateUserData({ uid, email, displayName, photoURL }) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(
      `users/${uid}`
    );

    const data: User = {
      uid,
      email,
      displayName,
      photoURL,
      status: 'online',
      karma: 0
    };

    return userRef.set(data, { merge: true });
  }
```

My problem is that in each sign-in this resets karma to 0.
How should I check the user is already in the Firestore database, and if he is already in, I wouldn't put there the **karma: 0**

I have tried to put a boolean called **"amINew"** into the constructor, and if it finds the user data in Firestore it should be false, and else true.

```
amInew: boolean;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router,
    public ngZone: NgZone
  ) {
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          this.amInew = false;
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          this.amInew = true;
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Problem with that was that **"amInew"** was always true, even when I tried it with a user that havent been registered.

How should I?

Comment: if you don't want to change the value of `karma`, why are you setting it as re-payload?

Comment: I want to, every user can change every users karma once, by +1 or -1

Comment: Okay, but still I don't understand why you are updating it to 0 in the first place if you don't want to ;)

Comment: well that would look weird if you just look up someones profile and his karma is missing, 0 is still better then nothing, Plus later it would be easier to acces karma, which is already there, then create a new,  I guess :D

Comment: I mean, just why in your code are you doing `karma: 0` if you don't want to set it as 0 when updating user, simple answer, just don't do it :D

Comment: Because I don't have a better idea how to set it to 0 if you register the first time, and don't set it when you've already registered. That's why I've come for help to the Stackoverflow gods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating karma like this:

```
const data: User = {
  uid,
  email,
  displayName,
  photoURL,
  status: 'online',
  karma: currentKarma + 1;
};
```

And you can check if the value karma to determine first signin.

During registration set the karma to 0

```
user.karma = 0;
```

Then on login

```
if (user.karma === 0) {
    // This means first signin
    user.karma = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have different functions for actually updating a user and "updating" a user when signing in for the first time. When signing up for the first time you would want to of course set the `karma` as `0`, but when user just signs in, you can call a function to update one or several fields with `update`. I see that you would probably want to call update on at least the status. So after login (not signing up) just update the `status field`:

```
private updateStatus(uid: string) {
  const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(
    `users/${uid}`
  );
  return userRef.update({status: 'online'});
}
```

Comment: By the way, building a presence service like this, I would still recommend the "old" firebase, i.e Realtime database. It has handy things for this usecase like `onDisconnect()` which automatically detects when user disconnects. But just how I feel like doing it :)